# Change wordpress files without FTP access and WP admin

Tags: wordpress, ftp, wordpress-theming, hosting

I have a wordpress.com website and I am facing some configuration issues.  I am unable to access the wp-admin page nor login. 
I also cannot access the ftp. I dont think I have a ftp for my site.

I need to make some changes and fix the corrupt htaccess file.

How can I achieve this?

I am very new to wordpress. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

You must have a control panel with your hosting package.. Please login to your control panel and search for File Manager or similar option.

Generally, for windows, your web content will be stored in wwwroot folder and in case of linux hosting, it will be in public_html folder. You must be able to find your .htaccess file there. If you are still unable to see this file, make sure that you have enabled hidden file option.